# Поиск противника игровой бот

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Вот есть игровой бот, к примеру гонки. Как сделать так, что один пользователь может начать поиск противника, и когда другой человек тоже нажмёт начать поиск, то они попадутся вместе и будет выполнено определённое действие, к примеру начисление игровых монет одному из игроков? Как именно код должен находить двух людей в поиске? Мне пришла мысль, чтобы когда игрок нажимает поиск, то его id заносится в базу, если в этой базе >2 id то их рандомно закидывает в игру между друг другом. Нормальная ли это идея, или можно как-то по-другому?

Comment: Не нужно задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз.

Comment: Там не ответили, сказали дополнить. Я дополнил.

Comment: Дополнять нужно исходный вопрос, а не создавать новый такой же.

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно создать список и добавлять туда людей. При добавлении проверяйте: если там уже есть кто-то, то удаляйте его и сразу начинайте игру, сообщая об этом обоим игрокам. Если там никого нет, то ничего не делайте соответственно.